Exporting polygon layer to KML retain same color
There are two situations, first, I export layers which has yellow polygon contour to KML, but it saved as red (ff0000ff). Second, I combine two layers which is made by red polygon and yellow polygon with MMQGIS and export to KML , but all of them forced to become red polygon.
What I expected: retain the same color.

Symbology is saved separately from the data itself by default. Have a look at embedded styles
